# app get crashed while navigating to RootViewController from Message popup

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I used `MFMessageComposeViewController` class for sending messages. My app get crashed in a  particular situation. i e, When Message UI popup comes, user presses home button, app goes background and when come back, I wrote the code to navigate to the `root view controller` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate. Please let me know if any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a crash report for us?

Comment: This is the error... "Assertion failed: (result == KERN_SUCCESS), function +[XPCMachSendRight wrapSendRight:], file /SourceCache/XPCObjects/XPCObjects-46/XPCMachSendRight.m, line 27."

Comment: I am also seeing this problem. Have you got any solution?

Comment: Remove break points if any...

Comment: Hey did u find the solution.Me too suffering from the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In app delegate you are assigning the `rootviewcontroller` and in `applicationDidBecomeActive` you are redirecting into `rootviewcontroller`, why not to try directly assign the `viewcontroller` instead of `rootviewcontroller`.. You can at least try it, not sure it will work but still try once..

Comment: Shyantanu, Thank you for ur suggestion... But its not working...getting the same error... "Assertion failed: (result == KERN_SUCCESS), function +[XPCMachSendRight wrapSendRight:], file /SourceCache/XPCObjects/XPCObjects-46/XPCMachSendRight.m, line 27."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was solved by removing the break points, as 120hit suggested.

But, since I needed the breakpoints to check the code, I found out that the reason was that my code tried to close a ViewController, so I put the "next code" inside the completion block:

```
 [presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        self.currentMatch = match;

        GKTurnBasedParticipant *firstParticipant =
        [match.participants objectAtIndex:0];

        if (firstParticipant.lastTurnDate) {
            [delegate takeTurn:match];
        } else {
            [delegate enterNewGame:match];

        }
}];
```